# Adapter wont refresh

Tags: android

I did `mListDataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` on the activity and got error. I try set it on base activity using `onActivityResult();`

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {     
       mListDataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();}
```

Comment: What is the Error ? post the StackTrace. Where do you call this method to update the Adapter ? Show your Activity of Fragment.

Comment: No error at all. Just dont work. I call on the activity which is with adapter, main activity, after recieving result from adding activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I found answer myself after properly passing data over intents.
```

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

```
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        if (requestCode == 1) {
            Object object = data.getSerializableExtra("item");
            mListDataAdapter.add(object);

        }

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear what you are trying to do in your code but I guess you are trying to update you adapter with the new data set you receive in your `onActivityResult();`

Here is how `notifyDataSetChanged()` works in most cases. First you have a data set and show them in your adapter. Later when you receive a new data set or you want to update one or more objects that you show in your adapter ;

1. You send the new data set to adapter. Let's say you have a public method in your adapter takes some arguments and manipulates the list of Objects in your adapter, which is defined as `List list = new ArrayList();` in your case
2. Then you call `notifyDataSetChanged()`

What second step does is that it forces your `getView`method to be called. So when it's called, it will use the list of objects which you just manipulated. So you will have a fresh new UI with the new information in your list of objects.

**EDIT**

When you delete the TODO from your database, you don't update your list about it, how your adapter can know about what you have just changed ? So once you delete or add anything from/to your database, you need to delete or add the same Item from/to your adapter. So you can call `mListDataAdapter.add` or `mListDataAdapter.remove` once the `deleteTodo(int id)` or `addTodo(View view)` is triggered.

Comment: Your words make sense, but I cant still figure out how to do this. How to update data.

Comment: If you share your activity code, and tell me what is happening in your onActivityResult, I can have more insights and help you.

Comment: My onActivity result does nothing but  mListDataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); cause adapter is in main activity. I updated with code of the calling activity.

Comment: I cannot still see where you initialize your `mListDataAdapter` and where you push data in it.

Comment: Posted Main activity. Hope this is not too much.

Comment: @saintPeter see the Edit in my Question. Let me know once you try it.

Comment: How can I get item if there is no position yet? mListDataAdapter.add(todoTitle); not working.

Comment: if you are sending an object with add method of the adapter, you need to notify data set changes right after `list.add(object);`. so add `notifyDataSetChanged()` into add method of your listview.

Comment: No, you don't. You only need to tell to your adapter about what you have deleted and added. That's all.